# Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate to previously opened file in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I encounter this problem frequently in notepad++: let's say i am editing a file. i want to copy contents from another file to this file. to do that i open the other file and select the contents that i want to copy. now i want to navigate back to the old file. is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate to the old file? and by extension a shortcut to navigate forward?

or else, does someone know of an editor for windows that supports this scenario? another problem with notepad++ is if i goto the windows menu, it shows me a list of all the files that are opened and i have to scroll manually through all the files to select the file i want to edit. would be nice if it supported a search box where one could type in the filename they want to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl + TAB` seems to do the trick. the same shortcut navigates back and forward so effectively it toggles between previous and current file.

Also try Pressing `Ctrl` followed by `n` `TABS` to navigate back and pressing `Ctrl+SHIFT` followed by `n` `TABS` to move forward

Comment: See my answer if that's not sufficient and a line-based navigation is needed

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Location Navigate plugin to solve your navigation issue:

- Jump to previous location: Ctrl -
- Jump to next location: Ctrl Shift -